# Error while exporting data of datatype "Text" in SQL Server 2008r2 to Excel data type "long text"

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2, export

I am new to Databases. I  am trying to export data from `SQL Server 2008r2 server` to `Excel 2010`. One of the columns in the Database is of type `text` and since I want to export the data into Excel 2010, I am selecting destination data type as `longtext`.

I am encountering the following error:

> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component “Data Conversion 0 – 0” (39) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input “Data Conversion Input” (40). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

**SQL Server Import and Export Wizard**

Further, I am successfully able to export the data if I choose Ignore error and Ignore truncation option, but this gives me truncated data.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Try setting [IMEX=1](http://sqlblog.de/blog/2009/04/ssis-excel-import-column-data-types/)

Comment: Hi 

I googled about setting imex=1. But everywhere it is mentioned in context of IMPORTING data from Excel to SQL Server. Is it applicable in context of EXPORTING from SQL Server to Excel as well?

Comment: Found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cd262a56-c5a4-42fe-9755-c3c2f8340e95/ssis-sql-text-column-export-to-excel?forum=sqlintegrationservices) Explicitly about exporting, just try if it doesn't work, you will rollback changes.